# Database Joins with single record with multiple coulmns

Tags: sql-server, database, join

**Industry Table**

```
+----+--------------+
| ID | IndustryName | 
+----+--------------+
|  1 |     Auto     |
|  2 |     Pets     |
+----+--------------+
```

**Images Table**

```
+----+------------+--------------+
| ID | IndustryId |   ImageURL   |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 |     1      |      URL1    |
|  2 |     1      |      URL2    | 
|  3 |     1      |      URL3    |  
+----+------------+--------------+
```

I wanna get result of Select Query as follows

```
 +----+------------+------------------+
 | ID | IndustryId |ImageURLContains  |  
 +----+------------+------------------+
 | 1  | Auto       |(URL1,URL2,URL3)  |
 +----+------------+------------------+
```

And we can have n number of URLS against one IndustryId.

Comment: is IndustryId and ImageURL are a composite key? or is IndustryId equals to ImageURL?

Comment: IndustryId of Image Table is referring to Industry table id as foreign key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try It With Stuff Function

```
CREATE TABLE Images_Table(ID INT ,IndustryId INT , IMageURL NVARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO Images_Table
SELECT 1,1,'URL1'UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'URL2'UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,'URL3'

SELECT
    ID IndstryId,IndustryName,
    STUFF(
        (
            SELECT ' ,'+ISNULL(IMageURL,'')
            FROM Images_Table t2
            WHERE t2.IndustryId=t1.ID
            ORDER BY t2.Id
            FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,2,'') ImageURL   
FROM (SELECT ID,ISNULL(IndustryName,'') IndustryName FROM Industry_Table) t1
```

Following Output I'm Getting it

```
IndstryId   IndustryName                                       ImageURL
----------- -------------------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           Auto                                               URL1 ,URL2 ,URL3
```